# How to parse a URI like this in Java

Tags: java, parsing, uri

I'm trying to parse the following URI : [http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN|en|你](http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN|en|%E4%BD%A0)

but got this error message :

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in fragment at index 34: http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN|en|你
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3028)
```

It's having problem with the "|" character, if I get rid of the "|", the last Chinese char is not causing any problem, what's the right way to handle this ?

My method look like this :

```
  public static void displayFileOrUrlInBrowser(String File_Or_Url)
  {
    try { Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(File_Or_Url.replace(" ","%20").replace("^","%5E"))); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
```

Thanks for the answers, but BalusC's solution seems to work only for an instance of the url, my method needs to work with any url I pass to it, how would it know where's the starting point to cut the url into two parts and only encode the second part ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The pipe character is ["considered unsafe"](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy) for use in URLs. You can fix it by replacing the | with its encoded hex equivalent, which would be "%7C"

However, replacing individual characters in a URL is a brittle solution that does not work very well when you consider that, in any given URL, there could potentially be quite a number of different characters that may need to be replaced. You are already replacing spaces, carets, and pipes.... but what about brackets, and accent marks, and quotation marks? Or question marks and ampersands, which may or may not be valid parts of a URL, depending on how they are used?

Thus, a superior solution would be to use the language's facility for encoding URLs, rather than doing it manually. In the case of Java, use [URLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html), as per the example in BalusC's answer to this question.

Comment: FYI: `URLEncoder` (despite the name) should not be used to encode URLs. The doc says: _This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format._ This is not the same as the encoding used by URIs/URLs.

Comment: BalusC's solution seems to work for this instance of the url, but I need the method to work for all urls I pass to it, how would it know from what starting point to parse the rest of the url ?

The url could any of the following :

www.yahoo.com/abc/xyz

http://yahoo.com/abc/123/

yahoo.com/abc/123/...

Comment: I think you would need to split the URL into pieces... domain, path, query string, and fragment. The domain should not get encoded. The path, you would have to split up by slashes, and encode each part of the path, then put it back together. For the query string, you would need to encode each parameter name and value. You would also have to encode the fragment. Then, reassemble the URL.

Answer (score 14):

The URLEncoder solution didn't work for me, maybe because it encodes just everything. I was trying to use apache's HttpGet and it throws error with a url as string encoded like that.

The correct way in my case was this strange code:

```
URL url = new URL(pageURLAsUnescapedString);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
```

Somehow url.toURI does not work the same way. URI constructors work in two ways: if you use the one with a single String parameter, the constructor pretends the provided uri is correctly escaped (and thus the error, the same happens with the String constructor of HttpGet); if you use the multiple Strings URI constructor, then the class handles everything unescaped very well (and HttpGet has another constructor accepting an URI). Why URL.toURI() does not do this? I have no clue...

Hope it helps someone, it took me some hours to figure it out.

Comment: This is wrong. If URL contains some encoded characters, space "%20" for example, as a result there will be unwanted "%2520". Take a look example [here](http://ideone.com/7uVSBj) or [my question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13530019/1387438).

Comment: @MarekR I took the best of your two answers and combined them at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22279061/14731

Answer (score 7):

Aren't you better off using [URLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) than selectively encoding stuff?

Comment: Per the link you supplied (and comment on the question), it's a "Utility class for HTML form encoding". It's not for URIs.

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`java.net.URLEncoder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to URL-encode the query with `UTF-8`. You don't necessarily need regex for this. You don't want to have a regex to cover all of those thousands Chinese glyphs, do you? ;)

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("zh-CN|en|你", "UTF-8");
String url = "http://translate.google.com/#" + query;
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
```

Comment: Per the link you supplied (and comment on the question), it's a "Utility class for HTML form encoding". It's not for URIs.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the best of [Federico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960779/14731) and [Marek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531165/14731), you need to do the following:

```
URL url = new URL(pageURLAsUnescapedString);

// URI's constructor expects the path, query string and fragment to be decoded.
// If we do not decode them, we will end up with double-encoding.
String path = url.getPath();
if (path != null)
  path = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
String query = url.getQuery();
if (query != null)
  query = URLDecoder.decode(query, "UTF-8");
String fragment = url.getRef();
if (fragment != null)
  fragment = URLDecoder.decode(fragment, "UTF-8");

URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), path, query, fragment);
```

Comment: `URLDecoder.decode(query, "UTF-8")` will decode ampersand in parameter values too early

Answer (score 0):

First encode your URL ,please use following example , then pass URL into method

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("name", "vaquar");
        json.put("age", "30");
        json.put("address", "asasbsa bajsb ");


        System.out.println("in sslRestClientGETRankColl"+json.toString());

        String createdJson=json.toString();

        createdJson= URLEncoder.encode(createdJson, "UTF-8");
```

//call method now 
displayFileOrUrlInBrowser(createdJson);

```
public static void displayFileOrUrlInBrowser(String File_Or_Url)
  {
    try { Desktop.getDesktop().browse(File_Or_Url); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I found how to do it, like this :

```
try { Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(File_Or_Url.replace(" ","%20").replace("^","%5E").replace("|","%7C"))); }
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```