# How to convert URL toURI when there are unwise characters?

Tags: java, http, url, uri

I've got URL object with path containing [unwise characters (RFC 2396)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.4.3) in my case it is "|" (pipe) character.
Now I need to safely convert that to URI, but [`URL.toURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) throws an exception.

I've read [URL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) but this part is for me confusing:

> The URL class does not itself encode or decode any URL components
> according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the
> responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be
> escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields,
> that are returned from URL. Furthermore, because URL has no knowledge
> of URL escaping, it does not recognize equivalence between the encoded
> or decoded form of the same URL.

So how should I do it? What is the pattern here to encode this characters during conversion? Do I need create encoded copy of my URL object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I come up with something like this:

```
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), 
                  null /*userInfo*/,
                  url.getHost(), 
                  url.getPort(), 
                  (url.getPath()==null)?null:URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), "UTF-8"),
                  (url.getQuery()==null)?null:URLDecoder.decode(url.getQuery(), "UTF-8"),
                  null /*fragment*/);
```

Looks like it works, [here is an example](http://ideone.com/ZUpAnJ). Can some one confirm that this is proper solution?

***Edit**: [initial solution](http://ideone.com/tCl7Yb) had some problems when there was a query so I've fixed it.*

Comment: This method alters URL as it url encodes parts of URL, see my solution

Comment: yes you are right, I've notice that some time ego, in ideone.com (see first link) I've corrected my solution and I've added extra test cases which reveal this problem. I will check your solution, it looks better.

Comment: By the way the bug you submitted on jmeter has been fixed yesterday, you can try nightly build

Comment: thats great, I thought that it won't be fixed. I will test this fix to verify that it relay works.

Comment: I've tested JMeter fix and it works perfectly. My solution is Ok, if someone doesn't want to use URIBuilder from Apache, but in other cases your solution is better.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4960779/14731 for a better/cleaner solution (for one, he retains the fragment)

Comment: @Gili I had to recall my self why I've added decode, and problem is visible [here](http://ideone.com/7uVSBj). Take a look on "uri.toString" results for examples where URL contains encoded characters like "%20" - encoding is corrupted.

Comment: @Gili if you read earlier comments you will noticed that I did same mistake :).

Comment: You're right about needing to decode, but you're still wrong about passing in a null userInfo and fragment. The correct answer is to add decoding to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4960779/14731.

Answer (score 1):

Use URL encoding?

From your example, you currently have:

```
URL url = new URL("http", "google.com", 8080, "/crapy|path with-unwise_characters.jpg");
```

Instead, I would use:

```
String path = "/crapy|path with-unwise_characters.jpg"
URL url = new URL("http", "google.com", 8080, URLEncoder.encode(path, "UTF-8"));
```

This should work and handle all unwise characters in the path as per the standard URL encoding.

Comment: this is OK solution, but my main aim was conversion to URI so my solution is more direct, especially that I do not create URL it comes from 3rd party code.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPClient 4 has an object for that org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder:

```
           URIBuilder builder = 
            new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme(url.getProtocol())
        .setHost(url.getHost())
        .setPort(url.getPort())
        .setUserInfo(url.getUserInfo())
        .setPath(url.getPath())
        .setQuery(url.getQuery());
    URI uri = builder.build();
    return uri;
```